# FakeFtpServer with Apache camel - fake user can't even login?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to integrate FakeFtpServer with Apache Camel, just to download file from the server. All the patchs included are correct, here's my code:

```
  FakeFtpServer fakeFtpServer = new FakeFtpServer();
        fakeFtpServer.addUserAccount(new UserAccount("ftpUser", "ftpPassword", ""));
        WindowsFakeFileSystem fileSystem = new WindowsFakeFileSystem();
        fileSystem.add(new FileEntry("C:/a/ftp/some_file.xml"));
        fakeFtpServer.setFileSystem(fileSystem);
        fakeFtpServer.start();

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        RouteBuilder rb = new RouteBuilder()
        {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception
            {
                from("ftp://ftpUser@localhost//a/ftp/?password=ftpPassword&passiveMode=true")
                                .to("file:C:/local");
            }
        };

        context.addRoutes(rb);
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        context.stop();

        fakeFtpServer.stop();
```

After running my code I see that Apache Camel is unable to connect:

```
[Thread-2] ERROR org.mockftpserver.fake.command.UserCommandHandler - UserAccount missing or not valid for username [ftpUser]: UserAccount[username=ftpUser; password=ftpPassword; homeDirectory=; passwordRequiredForLogin=true]
[Thread-2] INFO org.mockftpserver.fake.command.UserCommandHandler - Sending reply [530 UserAccount missing or invalid for user [ftpUser]] args=[ftpUser]
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[ftp://ftpUser@localhost//a/ftp/?passiveMode=true&password=xxxxxx]
```

I tried few tutorials, but no luck. Am I missing something ?

Comment: There's a mistake: localhost//a/ftp/ should be localhost/a/ftp/, but it doesn't change anything - error message is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things to correct.

1. the user home in the `UserAccount` is manadory
2. for the `WindowsFakeFileSystem` you need to instruct Camel not to step into each directory (see [stepwise changing directories](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html#FTP2-Stepwisechangingdirectories), otherwise the access by Camel will fail on a `CWD C:` (C: is the drive letter of the user home)

Find below working examples for the Windows and Unix fake filesystem and the Camel route to access the file with an absolute server path or a path relative to the user home.

**Windows absolute path**

```
public class WindowsAbsolutePath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FakeFtpServer fakeFtpServer = new FakeFtpServer();
        fakeFtpServer.setServerControlPort(2222);

        fakeFtpServer.addUserAccount(new UserAccount("ftpUser", "ftpPassword", "C:\\home"));
        WindowsFakeFileSystem fileSystem = new WindowsFakeFileSystem();
        // if the user home is not part of a `FileEntry` it must be explicit added
        fileSystem.add(new DirectoryEntry("C:\\home"));
        fileSystem.add(new FileEntry("C:\\a\\ftp\\some_file.xml", "windows absolute path"));

        fakeFtpServer.setFileSystem(fileSystem);
        fakeFtpServer.start();

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        RouteBuilder rb = new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // directory with absolute Windows path
                from("ftp://ftpUser@localhost:2222/C:/a/ftp?password=ftpPassword"
                        + "&passiveMode=true&stepwise=false")
                        .to("file:///tmp/local");
            }
        };

        context.addRoutes(rb);
        context.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        context.stop();

        fakeFtpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

**Windows relative path**

```
public class WindowsRelativePath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FakeFtpServer fakeFtpServer = new FakeFtpServer();
        fakeFtpServer.setServerControlPort(2222);

        fakeFtpServer.addUserAccount(new UserAccount("ftpUser", "ftpPassword", "C:\\home"));
        WindowsFakeFileSystem fileSystem = new WindowsFakeFileSystem();
        fileSystem.add(new FileEntry("C:\\home\\a\\ftp\\some_file.xml",
            "Windows relative path"));

        fakeFtpServer.setFileSystem(fileSystem);
        fakeFtpServer.start();

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        RouteBuilder rb = new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // directory with path relative to user home
                from("ftp://ftpUser@localhost:2222/a/ftp?password=ftpPassword"
                        + "&passiveMode=true&stepwise=false")
                        .to("file:///tmp/local");
            }
        };

        context.addRoutes(rb);
        context.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        context.stop();

        fakeFtpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

**Unix absolute path**

```
public class UnixAbsolutePath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FakeFtpServer fakeFtpServer = new FakeFtpServer();
        fakeFtpServer.setServerControlPort(2222);

        fakeFtpServer.addUserAccount(new UserAccount("ftpUser", "ftpPassword",
            "/home/remote"));
        UnixFakeFileSystem fileSystem = new UnixFakeFileSystem();
        fileSystem.add(new DirectoryEntry("/home/remote"));
        fileSystem.add(new FileEntry("/a/ftp/some_file.xml", "Unix absolute path"));

        fakeFtpServer.setFileSystem(fileSystem);
        fakeFtpServer.start();

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        RouteBuilder rb = new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // directory with absolute path
                from("ftp://ftpUser@localhost:2222//a/ftp?password=ftpPassword"
                        + "&passiveMode=true")
                        .to("file:///tmp/local");
            }
        };

        context.addRoutes(rb);
        context.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        context.stop();

        fakeFtpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

**Unix relative path**

```
public class UnixRelativePath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FakeFtpServer fakeFtpServer = new FakeFtpServer();
        fakeFtpServer.setServerControlPort(2222);

        fakeFtpServer.addUserAccount(new UserAccount("ftpUser", "ftpPassword",
             "/home/remote"));
        UnixFakeFileSystem fileSystem = new UnixFakeFileSystem();
        fileSystem.add(new FileEntry("/home/remote/a/ftp/some_file.xml",
             "Unix relative path"));

        fakeFtpServer.setFileSystem(fileSystem);
        fakeFtpServer.start();

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        RouteBuilder rb = new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // directory with path relative to user home
                from("ftp://ftpUser@localhost:2222/a/ftp?password=ftpPassword"
                        + "&passiveMode=true")
                        .to("file:///tmp/local");
            }
        };

        context.addRoutes(rb);
        context.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        context.stop();

        fakeFtpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue..try this add the directory before using it in user account creation.

```
fileSystem.add(new DirectoryEntry("c:\\data"));
```